# TouchableOpacity onPress() only one button is working

Tags: typescript, react-native

Not sure why only the first onPress is working, other onPress no response..., just use the same way to wrap the function, but other onPress didn't respond at all

```
const ToMainScreen = () => {
  navigation.navigate('Main')
}
const AskQuestion = () => {
  setQuestionDisplay(true)
  console.log("abc")
}
<TouchableOpacity onPress={ToMainScreen} >
  <Image
    style={styles.homeIcon}
    source={require('../image/homeIcon.png')}
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity >
  <Image
    style={styles.nextPageIcon}
    source={require('../image/nextPage.png',)} />
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity >
  <Image
    style={styles.previousPageIcon}
    source={require('../image/previousPage.png',)} />
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={AskQuestion}>
  <Image
    style={styles.questionIcon}
    source={require('../image/question.png',)} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the last one isn't working? The 2nd and 3rd `TouchableOpacity` elements aren't being passed handlers

Comment: May be some issue in "setQuestionDisplay(true)" please try just removing setQuestionDisplay line and check is it console.log() working or not

Comment: @Kai, yes, the last one, only the first one working, but the first one is also working occasionally...

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani, removed, but still not working~

Comment: Please, provide a definition for ```styles``` object.